# Is it possible to create and use "virtual" table in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, database

I have shopping cart and items are stored in session as array. Array key represents id of item, array value is amount of items. `array([1]=>1, [2]=>1);`

I want to calculate total price. Is it possible to make it using one mysql query?

For example:

```
SELECT SUM(c.count * i.price) FROM (--virtual table--) c 
                                        LEFT JOIN item i ON i.id=c.id;
```

Comment: yes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want this:

```
SELECT 1 AS product_id, 1 AS quantity
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 100
...
```

In any case, it looks less awkward to do one of these:

- Retrieve prices from database
- Store carts in database

That way you can do all your calculations at a single place.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to [Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) or [subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) - if so, then you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, since **data is in the session** *(unless you want to write the session data in the DB)*.
might i suggest this approach

```
SELECT i.id, i.price 
FROM item i 
WHERE i.id in (array.keys)
```

assuming result is placed in a collection,
let `itemResult` be the collection
then iterate

```
var total = 0
for(var item : itemResult)
  total += item.price * array[i.id]
```

`total` would contain the sum using this Pseudocode